# Getting this below error while file upload, this issue is reproducible in a slow network, Please suggest your thoughts here, Thank you

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, multer, loopback4

Getting below error while file upload, Connection getting timed out while uploading large files in slow network-

**Front End - Angular 9
Backend - Loopback 4, Node js, Multer package
File Storage - AWS s3**

POST http://13.233.150.107:8080/api/contentUpload/course-content/New%20Another%20cat/videos net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED

core.js:5871 ERROR
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://13.233.150.107:8080/api/contentUpload/course-content/New Another cat/videos", ok: false, …}
error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for http://13.233.150.107:8080/api/contentUpload/course-content/New Another cat/videos: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://13.233.150.107:8080/api/contentUpload/course-content/New Another cat/videos"
**proto**: HttpResponseBase

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd dig into Loopback's settings and try to find if it has a timeout enforced. Express.js by default doesn't have a timeout, it should let long uploads stay outstanding as long as they take.